# How to destroy vuejs component from outside of component

Tags: vue.js, components

I have created one of component in vuejs something like this

```
    var tree_data = Vue.extend({
        template: '#tree_data_template',
        props: [
            'groupmodal',
            'search-name',
            'tree-id'
        ], // props in single quotes
        data: function () {
            return {
                shared: d2d.store
            };
        }
    });
```

And use this component in another template like this.

```
var template_data = Vue.extend({
template: '#template_data',
created: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.shared.setCurrentRoute('templates');
},
components: {
    'tree-data': tree_data
},
data: function () {
    return {
        id: this.$route.params.id,
        shared: d2d.store,
    };
},
methods: {
    destroyComponent: function () {
        //Need to code for destroy tree-data component
    }
}
});
```

Blade file code

```
<tree-data 
     groupmodal="false"                 
     search-name="user_search" 
     tree-id="user_tree" 
>
</tree-data>
```

So finally how can i destroy my "tree-data" component through the "destroyComponent()" method

Comment: Just toogle it with v-if.

Comment: I want to destroy this component after generate not ignore to generate

Comment: @Cobaltway Thank for comment . I have do mistake in for understood your comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As **cobaltway** said you can use `v-if`

Setting   `v-if` initially to false will render(generate) the component.

Then in your method setting `v-if` to true will [destroy the component.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show)

**html**

```
<div id="template_data">
     <tree-data v-if="destroyComponent"></tree-data>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var template_data = Vue.extend({
template: '#template_data',
created: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.shared.setCurrentRoute('templates');
},
components: {
    'tree-data': tree_data
},
data: function () {
    return {
        id: this.$route.params.id,
        shared: d2d.store,
        destroyComponent:true
    };
},
methods: {
    destroyComponent: function () {
        //Need to code for destroy tree-data component
        this.destroyComponent = false;
    }
}
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmdv14p6/)

Comment: Thanks for answer but i want to destroy this component not conditionally hidden.
i want to something like this...
var components = this.$options.components['tree-data'];  
components.$destroy();

Comment: @Tester `v-if` will destroy the component. The `destroyed()` lifecycle hook will will be called. I will add a fiddle wait

Comment: @Tester added a link to the fiddle have a look